# looking for a more "data.table-ish" way to add a new column based on conditions from another

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements

I can add a conditional column like this:

```
dt$newcol <- ifelse(dt4$doy > 150 & dt4$doy < 280, 1, 0)
```

which adds the new column "newcol" to the data table "dt" and fills newcol with a 1 if doy is greater than 160 AND less than 280, otherwise fills with 0s.

I have been trying to get used to the data table syntax and I am wondering how to make use of the := oporator to do this in a more data table style?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please consider to show few lines of example data

Comment: Please clarify: `doy` is in a different data.table than `newcol`?

Comment: same data table, simply has a new column called "newcol" that uses  a condtion from the column doy. I'll add some sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
 library(data.table)
 dt4[,newcol:=(doy >150 & doy <280)+0L]
 head(dt4)
 #  doy         val newcol
 #1: 103 -1.35466363      0
 #2:  79 -0.96080882      0
 #3: 247  0.22495434      1
 #4: 182 -0.12316046      1
 #5: 232  0.00104102      1
 #6: 323 -0.57124325      0
```

Or you could use `as.integer` as commented by @Arun

```
 dt4[,newcol:= as.integer(doy>150 & doy < 280)]
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 dt4 <- data.table(doy=sample(1:350, 150, replace=TRUE), val=rnorm(150) )
```

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it if the output is only needed as 1/0 or TRUE/FALSE as in the example (+1).

Comment: @beginneR Thanks, But, if it something like (0, 99), you could `multiply`

Comment: Nice +1. Consider wrapping with `as.integer()` rather than `+ 0` - less cryptic. And if not, then do, `+ 0L`. The former coerces to `numeric` type which takes 8-bytes of storage.

Comment: @Arun Thanks, I will add `+0L`

Comment: Perfect! dt4[,newcol:= as.integer(doy>150 & doy < 280)] is exaclty what I was trying to come up with.